# how do I configure log4php to filter by classname?

Tags: log4php

Is there any way to configure log4php to output logs only for a given class?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there are two ways.

One is already supported by Log4php. You can configure to only log a specific logger:

```
log4php.logger.com.foo.Myclass=WARN
```

The other one is more complicated. You can create your own Filter:
http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appender-filter.html

A filter is a class which extends Log4PHP LoggerFilter interface. An example how a filter is implemented can be found here:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4php/trunk/src/main/php/filters/LoggerFilterStringMatch.php?view=markup

Cheers,
Christian